# reading from CSV and batch inserting to database Netezza

Tags: java, jdbc, netezza

I am reading a CSV file and inserting the data to Netezza DB. I would like to do a batch INSERT.
Some thing is wrong in my code and fails to INSERT the data.

No errors though.

```
while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    preparedStatement.setString(1,row[0]);
    preparedStatement.setString(2,row[1]);
    preparedStatement.setString(3,row[2]);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
csvReader.close();
```

But if I do individual INSERTs those work fine:

```
while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    preparedStatement.setString(1,row[0]);
    preparedStatement.setString(2,row[1]);
    preparedStatement.setString(3,row[2]);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
csvReader.close();
```

What's wrong with the first batch update?

Comment: Are you calling commit() on your db connection?

Comment: dbConnection.commit(); makes no difference

Comment: Netezza auto commits.

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: JDBC batch updates can call the netezza bulk loader under the covers, which can be more picky about data types that a normal update/insert over JDBC.  Can you verify what is happening in the pg.log from Netezza at the time your code runs?